# Entity Framework and WCF Data Members

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

1)

I have a Entity Framework (v.5) project which works with WCF.

My database has an Account table , and therefore I have an "Account" entity framework object.
I'd like to expose a method:

```
 AddAccount(Account a)
```

The Account Parameter is an entity framework object generated from my DataBase.

Each time that I try to consume this Service, the properties of Account are empty, and I can't understand why.

Here is an example of my code :

WCF :

Interface:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "AddAccount")]
string AddAccount(Account Account);
```

Implement:

```
public string AddAccount(Account newAccount)
{
    myContext db=new myContext();
    db.Accounts.Add(newAccount);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return "something";
}
```

Account Class is generated by the EF, and has an `int` "id" field, and `DateTime` "Created" field.

My question is, why is the "newAccount" parameter is empty?

2)

From what I know, the best way to expose a method with complex parameters is using `DataContract` and `DataMembers` , and that raises two questions that I'd like to ask.

a)Do I need to implement `DataContract` to an Entity object ? From what I understood its not recommanded to expose an EF object directly, but use `DataContract` on the class I'd like to transfer, but on the other hand, I get no error while trying to use my project , which doesn't implement `DataContract` on Account.

b) Why isn't it recommanded to pass EF object as parameters, besides letting the client understand my Database table's build?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your database you can assign identity specification to the id field and you can give a default value to your created field.

If you have the columns of id and created, you need to initialize Created. You don't need to initialize your id field unless it has no identity specification in your database. In general you need to initialize your values, because your database is not able to guess what values should be assigned to your properties.

So your entity is not created by the database, it is created by your method and it is empty, because you didn't initialize it. Example initialization

```
public string AddAccount()
{
    myContext db=new myContext();
    //id is not initialized, because I'm assuming it has an identity specification
    db.Accounts.Add(new Account() { Created = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()});
    db.SaveChanges();
    return "something";
}
```

Your entity class doesn't need to implement DataContract, my projects work impeccably using EF objects which are instances of classes which don't implement DataContract.

You can pass EF objects as parameter in your business logic, there is absolutely no problem with that. You only have to be careful to not let your clients know what the schema of your database is.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Lajos, but it isn't the issue here, obviously I have much more fields that I have to fill in and "CreationDate" and "ID" are just examples of many fields

Comment: You didn't understand my answer, @Rasuli. My answer has shown you how to initialize Created, which is another field. If you have more fields and you intend to have initial values stored for them, you need to initialize your other fields too.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the answer, indeed I have tried to pass these parameters, whether they are POCO entities or class which I define as DataContract. The problem I'm having at the moment is that the objects I'm sending are recieved with empty/null Properties, and I can't understand why, the funny thing is that when I try to test the "AddAccount" in WCF Test Client, the parameter is being passed without nulls, and when I try to consume this service from another application , the parameter passes as null.

Comment: Then your problem is essentially a communication problem. I think you should study the communication protocol used in the other services, maybe you are going to find the flaw this way. I wish you the best of luck with that.